# Sort Arraylist in alphabetical order

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm making a `listView` from an `arrayList`. Now i want the `listView` to be sorted alphabetically.. I've searched online already but none of it worked.. How can I achieve it?

My code:

```
String[] Hospitals = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hospitals);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Hospitals);

mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

"Hospitals" is a list in my strings.xml file.

Comment: "I've searched online already but none of it worked", what did you search and tried?

Comment: Why not just sort arrayList ?

Comment: This is the method for sorting List https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List<T>)  just make an ArrayList out of your array and use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like you said it Hospitals is not an Arraylist but just a String array (String[]) so you will need to use this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(etst);
```

Then you can use the following code to sort

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
        });
```

If you want it ignoreCase:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort an array with Arrays.sort(Hospitals).